# Will the following sentence still be grammatical if I remove the "of them"?

Tags: grammar

> I explored every inch of the beach: its rocks, its reefs, its shoreline,
>   all (of them) coated with green moss.

Can I omit that "of them"? Why or why not?

Comment: Grammatical to omit "of them".  *All* can be used nominally.   "All" could also be taken adverbially  -- "all coated" meaning "entirely coated", or "very much coated".  One could say "Those rocks are *all slippery* with moss".

Comment: And if you slipped and fell into the water, you would be *all wet*.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples are grammatically correct but omitting *of them* changes the meaning: *all* would then apply to just the shoreline (i.e. *all* the shoreline coated with green).

Consider if the order of words were changed, to make it more obvious:

**I explored every inch of the beach: its rocks, its shoreline, all coated with green, its reefs.**